# How can I create a directory on the file system?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, directory

How do you create a physical directory on the OS from within PL/SQL? I looked at the `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY` command but that doesn't do it. Neither does `UTL_FILE` appear to be capable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I did find an easier solution. Use

```
select os_command.exec('mkdir /home/oracle/mydir') from dual;
```

or simply

```
x := os_command.exec('mkdir /home/oracle/mydir');
```

Comment: i'll just add a link to os_command here since i did not know about it before.. http://plsqlexecoscomm.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

`UTL_FILE` still lacks this capability - probably a holdover from the pre-`DIRECTORY` object days where you had to explicitly define the OS file directories you could access in a startup parameter, so there was no need to create directories dynamically anyway.

I think the easiest way to do this is with an Oracle Java stored procedure that uses:

```
    File f = new File(dirname);
    return (f.mkdir()) ? 1 : 0;
```

If you go this route make sure that you use `dbms_java.grant_permission` to grant `java.io.FilePermission` to the user that owns the executing code.

Comment: Thanks for this. I hate having to write Java unless absolutely forced to. In the end I found an easier way, using PLSQL by using os_command.exec together with mkdir. See my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is to use an external procedure (C or Java) and call it through PL/SQL.  PL/SQL itself does not have the means to create the physical OS directory.

[PL/SQL Tips](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/PL_SQL/PLSQL_1.shtml) provides a good example of how to create a C external procedure that executes shell commands.  Note that I would not consider it best practice to allow this for security reasons.

It you can create the directory first, then you can use the

`create or replace directory myDir as '<path-to-dir>/myDir';`

Note that you will need to have the CREATE ANY DIRECTORY privilege assigned to the user executing the command. After the directory is created with the command above, be sure to assign any needed privileges on the directory to other users.

```
grant read, write on directory myDir to testUsers;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the new docs for database version 11.2, and there's still no routine I can find to create a directory. So, like the other respondents, I recommend using a Java or C routine.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute OS commands from within Oracle using [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810896/429100) or internal Java procedure, for example, using my [XT_SHELL](https://github.com/xtender/xt_shell) package:

1. install it using `install.sql`:
   [image]
2. Execute OS command using `xt_shell.shell_exec(pCommand in varchar2,timeout in number)` in SQL or PL/SQL:

```
SQL> select * from table(xt_shell.shell_exec('/bin/mkdir /tmp/test-dir',1000));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> select * from table(xt_shell.shell_exec('/bin/mkdir /tmp/test-dir/test-dir2',1000));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> select * from table(xt_shell.shell_exec('/bin/ls -l /tmp/test-dir',1000));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle oinstall 4096 Apr 19 12:14 test-dir2
```