# Create a directory in a PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am looking for a way to create a directory inside a PL/SQL procedure.

I have a `directory_path` from a `directory_name` that I know and then I would like to add a directory from this `directory_path`. For example my `directory_path` is `/home/oracle` and the procedure receives a parameter ,`30`. I want to create `/home/oracle/30`.

At the beginning, I don't know the parameter 30 so I can't create the directory before launching the procedure.

Is it mandatory to use Dynamic SQL or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554079/in-oracle-pl-sql-how-do-i-create-a-directory-on-the-file-system

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't enable java in the database...

Comment: Why not @jacen44? Your DBA's should be able to give you that option, it's possible to strictly control it by creating the Java in a different schema, which no one has access to and then granting the ability to use it to other schemas restrictively.

Comment: @Ben The OP might be running XE, which comes without Java.

Comment: Do you want to create a (real) directory in the filesystem or an Oracle "directory object" (using `create directory`)

Comment: I want a real directory in the file system. It's not what `create directory` does ?

Comment: @jacen44 - no a DIRECTORY object in Oracle is just an alias to the path on the file system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done this in 10.2 with DBMS_Scheduler, which allows you to define a "program" which calls an external procedure -- either a unix command directly or more commonly a shell script.