# Dynamically create folder in plsql procedure in server

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I hve written a pl/sql procedure :

```
PROCEDURE xx_WriteBLOBToFILE (myfilename IN VARCHAR2,L_PERSON_ID IN NUMBER) IS 

  v_blob         BLOB;
  blob_length    INTEGER;
    out_file utl_file.file_type;
  v_buffer       RAW(32767);
  chunk_size     BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
  Blob_Position  Integer := 1;
   G_Zipped_Blob Blob;
B_Dl_File1 Blob;
BEGIN

  -- Retrieve the BLOB for reading
  Select Image Into V_Blob From Per_Images 
  Where Parent_Id =L_PERSON_ID;

  -- Retrieve the SIZE of the BLOB
  blob_length:=DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(v_blob);

  -- Open a handle to the location where you are going to write the BLOB to file
  -- NOTE: The 'wb' parameter means "write in byte mode" and is only availabe
  --       in the UTL_FILE package with Oracle 10g or later
  Out_File := Utl_File.Fopen ('**INT_DIR_IMG_BLOB**', Myfilename, 'wb', Chunk_Size);

  -- Write the BLOB to file in chunks 
  WHILE blob_position <= blob_length LOOP
    IF blob_position + chunk_size - 1 > blob_length THEN
      chunk_size := blob_length - blob_position + 1;
    End If;

    DBMS_LOB.READ(v_blob, chunk_size, blob_position, v_buffer);
    UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW(out_file, v_buffer, TRUE);
    blob_position := blob_position + chunk_size;
  END LOOP;

  -- Close the file handle
  Utl_File.Fclose (Out_File);
End;
```

I want to dynamically create the folder in /Blobfile in a location and then create the directory like INT_DIR_IMG_BLOB dynamically.

How can i create the folder in the server in plsql

Answer (score 1):

If the operating system directory does not already exist, you probably can't create it directly in PL/SQL.  You could create a Java stored procedure (or a .Net stored procedure if your database runs on Windows) that creates the operating system directory and call that from PL/SQL.  You could also create a `dbms_scheduler` job that calls out to the operating system to create the directory and call that from PL/SQL.

Once the operating system directory exists, you can create the Oracle directory object using dynamic SQL.  You'd also, presumably, need to grant privileges on that directory object to users dynamically.

```
execute immediate 'create directory ' || directory_name_you_want ||
                  ' as ''' || directory_path || '''';
execute immediate 'grant read on ' || directory_name_you_want ||
                  ' to some_role';
```

You could then use the newly created directory in your code.

Although you could do this, I would generally advise you not to go down this path.  Dynamically creating objects at runtime is generally a poor idea, it's going to make your code a lot more complicated and much harder to support.  And it creates lots of opportunities for things to go wrong in new and interesting ways.

Comment: this means i cannot create a new folder inside a directory in plsql ?

Comment: @sreekembose - Pure PL/SQL does not have the ability to create a new subdirectory at an operating system level, no.  PL/SQL can call out to Java or .Net or to the operating system to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DBMS_SCHEDULER for create the folder in os.
1. create credentials.
2. write scheduler for external job execution.

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_CREDENTIAL.CREATE_CREDENTIAL(
      credential_name  =>  'credintial',   ----- credintial name give by u
      username         =>  'dons',          ----- os username
      password         =>  'password');    ----- os password
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MAKEFOLDER AS 
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB 
(JOB_NAME=>'folder_maker',       --- job name 
JOB_ACTION=>'mkdir /home/anil/new_folder',    --- executable file with path 
JOB_TYPE=>'executable',        -----   job type
NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS=>0,  --  parameters in numbers 
ENABLED=>false,                   
AUTO_DROP =>true,
CREDENTIAL_NAME=>'credintial',   -- give credentials name which you have created before "credintial"
COMMENTS=> 'folder or os directory creation');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('folder_maker');
END ;

EXEC PROC_MAKEFOLDER;
```