# How to Create folder from PLSQL command window using sql during spool

Tags: windows, plsql, directory, sqlplus, spool

I have tried `HOST MKDIR` os command from my spool code and folder is not creating from windows location.
Please help.

Below are some snipper tried.

```
HOST MKDIR 'DDL'
HOST MKDIR DDL
HOST MKDIR &foldaer_name
HOST MKDIR "DDL"
! MKDIR 'DDL'
$ MKDIR 'DDL'
```

Expecting the folder should be created in provided windows location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a directory on the file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554079/how-can-i-create-a-directory-on-the-file-system)

Comment: does `\! mkdir <dirname>` work?

Comment: this is sqlplus, not pl/sql